# Changing values/character based on a specific pattern in R

Tags: r

```
Title <- c("The diabetes drug liraglutide reverses cognitive impairment in mice and attenuates insulin receptor and synaptic pathology in a non-human primate model of Alzheimer's disease", 
           "Neuroprotective effects of the anticancer drug NVP-BEZ235 (dactolisib) on amyloid-β 1–42 induced neurotoxicity and memory impairment", 
           "Rivastigmine transdermal patch and physical exercises for Alzheimer's disease: A randomized clinical trial", 
           "Physical Exercise During Pregnancy Prevents Cognitive Impairment Induced by Amyloid-β in Adult Offspring Rats", 
           "Chronic sleep restriction promotes brain inflammation and synapse loss, and potentiates memory impairment induced by amyloid-β oligomers in mice", 
           "PQM130, a novel feruloyl-donepezil hybrid compound, effectively ameliorates the cognitive impairments and pathology in a mouse model of Alzheimer's disease")

A <- c(1:6)

B <- c(10:15)

C <- c("green", "yellow", "red", "blue", "white", "purple")

df <- data.frame(Title, A, B, C)
```

I want to replace values or characters in columns B and C with null values "" if the column Title contains the following words: mouse, mice, rat, rats.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_detect` to detect those animals. If found, replace the whole centence with ""

```
library(tidyverse)
pat <- '\\bmouse|mice|rats?\\b'

df %>%
    mutate(across(B:C, ~replace(.x, str_detect(Title, pat), '')))
```

---

Only printing the mutated columns:

```
  A  B      C
1 1          
2 2 11 yellow
3 3 12    red
4 4 13   blue
5 5          
6 6
```

Comment: A bunch of thanks, @Onyambu! It worked pretty well in my data.frame.